# kendo-vue dropdownlist inside window not working

Tags: kendo-ui, vuejs2

i've been struggling with this a couple of hours, but i don't find any way to make it work.

the thing is that the dropdownlist doesn't work if you put it inside a window. here you have an example.

https://plnkr.co/edit/eBpc4kEcHr7uSq6Zdq6h?p=preview

```
<kendo-window :width="'300px'" :title="'Window title'" :visible="visible" style="display:none">
```

```
<kendo-datasource ref="datasource" :type="'odata'" :transport-read-url="'https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products'">
</kendo-datasource>

<kendo-dropdownlist :data-source-ref="'datasource'" :data-text-field="'ProductName'" :data-value-field="'ProductID'" :placeholder="'Select product'">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products'">

is there a workaround for this?

regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with what you are trying, but it works with an [internal slot datasource](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/datasource/#toc-using-an-internal-slot-element):

```
  <kendo-window
          :width="'300px'"
          :title="'Window title'"
          :visible="visible"
          style="display:none">

      <kendo-dropdownlist
              :data-text-field="'ProductName'"
              :data-value-field="'ProductID'"
              :option-label="'Select product'">

          <kendo-datasource
                  slot="kendo-datasource"
                  :type="'odata'"
                  :transport-read-url="'https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products'">
          </kendo-datasource>

      </kendo-dropdownlist>

  </kendo-window>
```

Comment: sorry i'm not used to use kendo controls, it was just a test.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug - I have logged it [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/4039). You can use temporary use the internal slot (as suggested by rareclass) as [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/wLYx2LzZj2QgGBf98KAS?p=preview)

```
 <kendo-window :width="'300px'"
              :title="'Window title'"
              :visible="visible"
              style="display:none">
    <h4>Window content</h4>
        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width: 100%" :data-text-field="'ContactName'" >
        <kendo-datasource slot="kendo-datasource"
                          :type="'odata'"
                          :transport-read-url="'https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers'"
                          :group-field="'Country'">
        </kendo-datasource>
   </kendo-dropdownlist>
</kendo-window>
```